# Add alias to subquery in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, subquery, polygon, postgis

This has been driving me nuts for the past 2 hours:

I'm trying to query for overlapping polygons. This works nicely with PostGIS-functions, but i'm having a hard time in writing this query with SQLAlchemy.

The proper SQL-Query is:

```
SELECT id FROM track WHERE ST_Overlaps(
  (
    SELECT ST_GeomFromText(
      'POLYGON((
        16.15 47.25, 
        16.15 46.57, 
        13.85 46.57, 
        13.85 47.25, 
        16.15 47.25
      ))', 
    4326)
  ), 
  track.extent
);
```

(***track.extent*** is a column that holds polygons in geo-format, ***ST_GeomFromText()*** creates the polygon i'm comparing them to)

I'm using ORM and my python-code looks like this so far:

```
viewport = select([func.ST_GeomFromText(('POLYGON(( \
  16.15 47.25, \
  16.15 46.57, \
  13.85 46.57, \
  13.85 47.25, \
  16.15 47.25))' \
  ,4326))])

DBSession.query(Track.id).filter( \
  func.ST_Overlaps(viewport, Track.extent)).all()
```

The code above is interpreted by SQLAlchemy as the following SQL-Query:

```
SELECT track.id AS track_id FROM track, 
(SELECT ST_GeomFromText('
  POLYGON((
    16.15 47.25, 
    16.15 46.57, 
    13.85 46.57, 
    13.85 47.25, 
    16.15 47.25
  ))', 
  4326) AS "ST_GeomFromText_1"
) 
WHERE ST_Overlaps(
  (
    SELECT ST_GeomFromText(
      'POLYGON((
        16.15 47.25, 
        16.15 46.57, 
        13.85 46.57, 
        13.85 47.25, 
        16.15 47.25
      ))', 
      4326) AS "ST_GeomFromText_1"
    ), 
  track.extent
);
```

which yields in an ERROR:

```
 ProgrammingError: (ProgrammingError) subquery in FROM must have an alias
 LINE 2: FROM track, (SELECT ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((16.15759034023...
                     ^
 HINT:  For example, FROM (SELECT ...) [AS] foo.
```

How can i tell sqlalchemy to either get rid of the unnecessary ***viewport***-subquery in the FROM-clause or add an alias to the ***viewport***-query?

Comment: Why do you need a subquery in the first place? Can't you just do `viewport = func.ST_GeomFromText(...)` or does that not work?

Comment: @univerio no, that's not working - also in SQL the function needs to be called with SELECT, calling the function without SELECT gives a syntax error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are looking for the [`.label()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/selectable.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.SelectBase.label) construct:

```
viewport = select([func.ST_GeomFromText(...)]).label("viewport")
```

Then, putting that in the WHERE clause does not also put it in the FROM clause:

```
str(session.query(Track.id).filter(func.ST_Overlaps(viewport, Track.extent))
# 'SELECT track.id AS track_id \nFROM track \nWHERE ST_Overlaps((SELECT ST_GeomFromText(...) AS "ST_GeomFromText_1"), track.extent)'
```

Comment: May i ask how you found the solution? Have you just properly read up on the sqlalchemy-docs or did know it from experience?

Comment: @ChristianBenke I've used `.label` before, and it seemed appropriate in this case (a scalar subquery), so I just tried it and it worked.